# Trying to retrieve image - getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error

Tags: ios, image, cell, tableview

I saved a picture to NSData with UserDefaults and now want it to be retrieved in a tableview cell.

Here is what I put in the ViewDidLoad of the TableView.m

```
NSData *imageData;
imageData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourUIImage];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];
```

And here is what I put in the TableView cellforRowatIndex

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:@"bild"];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

However when I start the programe I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error at the cell.imageView.image line together with a "incompatible pointer types sending "NSString*" to paramater of type "NSData*""

Here is btw how I save the image in the first place:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"] == nil) { 
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    NSData *imageData;
    UIImage *yourUIImage;
    imageData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourUIImage];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` as a counterpart to `NSKeyedArchiver` like this:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey: @"image"];
cell.imageView.image = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: imageData];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Error are all gone, but instead of showing the image, I get an arrow pointing to the right in the cell.

Comment: And I think I now the problem to that, he doesnt save anything in the @"image" key ...

Comment: @Blade As far as I can see, you need to initialize `yourUIImage` with an actual `UIImage` before archiving it to user defaults.

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

"incompatible pointer types sending "NSString*" to paramater of type "NSData*""

An NSString was supplied as a parameter instead of an NSData.

Looking at your method invocation line:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:@"bild"];
```

The parameter is an NSString: `@"bild"`.

The documentation for `UIImage imageWithData` is:

data: The image data. This can be data from a file or data you create programmatically.

 you need to get the image data from the `NSArchive` and supply it (the data) to the `imageWithData` method.

It always pays to read and understand the error messages even it it takes some time to figure them out.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'm farily new to programming and read up on the error message, but thought that I would do it the right way and may have made another error (As Im saving it in NSData). If I understand you correctly I have to get the data from "yourUIImage", correct? I tried that but then it won't show me the image just an arrow pointing to the right in the cell.

Comment: See the answer by @Costique for how to handle `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. My answer is more along the lines of how to understand error message.